# The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception in kubernetes pods with C#.net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm calculating the width and height of an image using System.Drawing.Common.
Logic is completely working fine in Windows machine. When I deployed it on Linux Server by creating Kuberenetes Pods , Im getting the "The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception".
Is there any way to fix this issue from C# side . Not interested to add/modify build scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix this issue from C# side . Not interested to add/modify build scripts

No.  System.Drawing.Common has platform dependencies.  They are always there on Windows, but must be installed on Linux.

> NOTE that on Ubuntu (and other Linuxes) you may need to install some
> native dependencies as System.Drawing sits on top of native libraries
>
> sudo apt install libc6-dev
> sudo apt install libgdiplus

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-you-use-systemdrawing-in-net-core

Comment: for macOS users: `brew install mono-libgdiplus` did the trick